# Generating auto incrementing numbers with two columns

Tags: mysql, database

I want to create a table so that I have an ID number that is based on the date, AND an ID as a unique, primary key.

Ie:

```
2015-2-1-1
2015-2-1-2
```

but, if I create:

```
2015-2-2-1
```

the counter should restart at 1.

I've tried using the following:

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `date` date NOT NULL,
  `po_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `description` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
  `client_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `status` enum('unpaid','paid','partial') DEFAULT 'unpaid',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`,`date`),
  UNIQUE KEY `id_UNIQUE` (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=10 DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

But it doesn't work like I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want a two column primary key (date, id) and id that should auto increment starting from 1 each date. Just set `date`, for your primary column key, and `id` in second position in your key definition.

```
CREATE TABLE `invoices` (
   `date` date NOT NULL,
   `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
   `po_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `description` varchar(256) NOT NULL,
   `client_id` int(11) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
   `status` enum('unpaid','paid','partial') DEFAULT 'unpaid',
   PRIMARY KEY (`date`, `id`)
 ) ENGINE=MyIsam DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1;
```

The internal key will be set as your example, but you will see two columns:

```
+----+------------+
| id | date       |
+----+------------+
| 1  | 2012-01-01 |
| 2  | 2012-01-01 |
| 1  | 2012-01-02 |
| 2  | 2012-01-02 |
+----+------------+
```

EDIT: You have to use MyIsam format

Comment: Thank you! Is there any problems with doing something like this? Should it be avoided or is it okay?

Comment: There would not be any performance problem, the main problem will be the usability of a dual key to edit/store/delete the data (ie. providing two informations to access one row)

Comment: Im going to have something like invoice_items to store items belonging to an invoice. Will it be problematic to make the join across those two? Or is it just a matter of using two joins for date and id?

Comment: Hi, I'm getting this error: `Error Code: 1075. Incorrect table definition; there can be only one auto column and it must be defined as a key`

Comment: sorry my mistake, you have to invert date and id on the 2nd and first line. i have edited

Comment: for invoice_items you will have to have two column in invoice_item too. It is not problematic, but it do not make things easy.

Comment: Hi Adam. Sorry, it seems like I am still getting the same Error code 1075 even with the new code you updated.